# Simple js calculator with radio tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found subjects like mine but I could not fix my problem. So I wanted to calculate the cost of tickets form radio tags by multiplying the price with the amount of tickets using if statements for each option without jquery. I can not figure it out why I do not have an output. It looks like none of my functions work and I can not find why.

Can you help me please, I know it is easy but I am still a beginner

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>No Boundaries</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles1.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function validate(){
   if(!document.form1.cond.checked)
    {alert("Please accept the Terms and Conditions");
    return false;
   }
   if(document.form1.name.value.length < 2)
    {alert(“Please enter your full name, not just an initial”);
    return false;
   }
   return true;
  }
  function cost() {
   if (document.form1.accom["v"].checked) {
    var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
    var ans = 90 * amount;
    document.form1.total1.value = ans;
   } 
   else if (document.form1.accom["t"].checked) {
    var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
    var ans = 150 * amount;
    document.form1.total1.value = ans;
   } 
   else if (document.form1.accom["c"].checked) {
    var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
    var ans = 45 * amount;
    document.form1.total1.value = ans;
   }
  }
  function post(){
   if(document.form1.del["1"].checked){
    var num = 0;
    var ans = num;
    document.form1.total2.value = ans;
   }
   if(document.form1.del["2"].checked){
    var num = 12;
    var ans = num;
    document.form1.total2.value = ans;
   }
   if(document.form1.del["3"].checked){
    var num = 16;
    var ans = num;
    document.form1.total2.value = ans;
   }
   if(document.form1.del["4"].checked){
    var num = 20;
    var ans = num;
    document.form1.total2.value = ans;
   }
  }
  function damage(){
   var total1 = parseInt(document.form1.total1.value);
   var total1 = parseInt(document.form1.total1.value);
   var ans = total1 + total2;
   document.form.total3.value = ans;
  }
 </script>

</head>

<body>
<section>
  <form name="form1">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Personal details</legend>
   <div>
    Please enter your full name<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" required onsubmit="return validate();"><br>
   </div>
   <div>
    Address<br>
    <input name="addresss" type="text" required><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
   </div>
   <div>
    Phone Number<br>
    <input name="phone" type="tel"><br>
   </div>
   <div>
    Email Address<br>
    <input name="email" type="email" required><br>
   </div>
   <div>
    Date of Birth<br>
    <input name="birth" type="date"><br>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Ticket Details</legend>
    <div>
     Type of T<br>
     <label for="vil">V</label>
     <input type="radio" name="accom[]" value="v">
     <label for="town">T</label>
     <input type="radio" name="accom[]" value="t">
     <label for="con">C</label>
     <input type="radio" name="accom[]" value="c">
    </div>
    <div>
     Quantity of T
     <input name="amount" type="number" min="1" max="10" required><br>
     <br>
     <input type="button" name="cost" value="C C" onclick="cost();"><br>
    </div>
    <div>
     Delivery Options<br>
     <input type="radio" name="del[]" value="1" >Free<br>
     <input type="radio" name="del[]" value="2" >£12<br>
     <input type="radio" name="del[]" value="3" >£16<br>
     <input type="radio" name="del[]" value="4" >£20<br>
     <br>
     <input type="button" value="C D" onclick="post();"><br>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Terms And Conditions</legend>
   <input name="cond" type="checkbox" onsubmit="return validate();">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Cost</legend>
   <input type="text" name="total1" readonly><br>
   <input type="text" name="total2" readonly><br>
   <input type="text" name="total3" readonly><br>
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="C F C" onclick="damage();"><br>
  </fieldset>
  <br><br>
  <fieldset>
   <input type="submit">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you put the whole html or part of it, but does it contain the <form> tag ?

Comment: Where exactly is the form1in HTML  you are trying to find? is there anymore markup?

Comment: Yeah the form tag is included <form name="form1">

Comment: Check you console for errors.You are even missing <form></form>.Check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp

Comment: Sorry for not including it, in my actual code is there. The 3 dots is more code that does not have any role in my calculations.

Comment: And what does this all have to do with [java], [python] or [css]? Your problem seems to be just javascript-related, so please tag accordingly. This is not instagram. #nofilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found your errors. This is the code for html

```
<div>
   Type of T<br>
   <label for="vil">V</label>
   <input type="radio" name="accom" value="v">
   <label for="town">T</label>
   <input type="radio" name="accom" value="t">
    <label for="con">C</label>
</div>
<div>
   Quantity of T
   <input name="amount" type="number" min="1" max="10" required><br>
   <br>
   <input type="button" name="cost" value="C C" onclick="costs();"><br>
 </div>
```

Next, in your javascript you have tho change the name of function; instead of cost you have to renaming in **costs**

```
 function costs() {
    if (document.form1.accom.value == 'v') {
        var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
        var ans = 90 * amount;
        document.form1.total1.value = ans;
    } 
    else if (document.form1.accom.value == 't') {
        var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
        var ans = 150 * amount;
        document.form1.total1.value = ans;
    } 
    else if (document.form1.a`enter code here`ccom.value == 'c') {
        var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
        var ans = 45 * amount;
        document.form1.total1.value = ans;
    }
}
```

That's all

Comment: Yes, it is. No problem

Answer (score 1):

the cost function should be something like this,

```
function cost() {
    if (document.form1.accom.value.toLowerCase() == "v") {
        var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
        var ans = 90 * amount;
        document.form1.total1.value = ans;
    } else if (document.form1.accom.value.toLowerCase() == "t") {
        var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
        var ans = 150 * amount;
        document.form1.total1.value = ans;
    } else if (document.form1.accom.value.toLowerCase() == "c") {
        var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
        var ans = 45 * amount;
        document.form1.total1.value = ans;
    }
}
```

And to make the code more refactored, make it like this,

```
function cost() {
    var val = document.form1.accom.value.toLowerCase();
    var amount = parseInt(document.form1.amount.value);
    var ans;
    if (val == "v") {
        ans = 90 * amount;
    } else if (val == "t") {
        ans = 150 * amount;
    } else if (val == "c") {
        ans = 45 * amount;
    }
    document.form1.total1.value = ans;
}
```